# Implementing infinite scrolling and lazy loading data using Javascript and JSP

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, jsp

I am trying to implement lazy-loading of data (infinite scrolling). As of now, my code does the following:

1. It fetches the complete list of items from the server.
2. It displays six items at a time on the user's screen. As soon as the the user hits the end-of-scroll, it displays more data.

So, the program is not really fetching pages from the server on demand, but requesting the entire data at once, and displaying it, six items at a time.

I want it to fetch a page from the server every time the scrollbar hits the bottom of the screen. What is plan is that using the custom directive, I can detect the event, and then make an AJAX call to the server. Here are my questions:

1. How do it keep a count of which page to fetch? Do I need to keep track of the page state and page key? How do I do that?
2. How do I write the JSP for this?

My backend service isn't capable of generating paginated results as of now, so really, I just need to figure out the way to store the page state and writing the JSP.

Comment: where is code? ... AJAX can be hard with manually used "raw jsp". What framework do You know?

Comment: I am using the Spring MVC framework, and am quite new to it.